# Disable trigger on branch changes in scheduled trigger

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I try to specify in a yml file that a job should be run at 4 every morning if there are changes in the master branch.

The yml file starts like:

```
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: '0 4 * * *'
  displayName: Testing daily run
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

However, this is triggered upon every change of the master branch.
Why?

## Trying to list triggers in the UI

I got a suggestion that I could check if there is any trigger for the pipeline that could possibly override the yaml schedule.

If I edit the pipeline, there is a "Trigger issues" menu

[image]

resulting in an empty view

[image]

so I am still without a solution.

(The "scheduled runs" menu actually lists the next runs as expected, but adds a timezone offset of 2 hours)

## Triggers listed when editing a pipeline

When clicking the Edit button in a pipeline, I get a menu like

[image]

and when I click triggers it seems like I have nothing that disturbs my yaml schedules, but I may be wrong, the checkbox "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" is not checked. Maybe the list of disturbing triggers is empty (maybe not).

[image]

Comment: Do you have any triggers set in the UI? (can be seen by editing the pipeline, clicking the three dots and choosing triggers) Any triggers that are set here will override the yaml triggers

Comment: This isn't quite what I suggested. Let me grab some screenshots and post an answer

Comment: Maybe I should stop thinking about scheduling as a feature to accomplish with yaml, only using the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

As per my commented suggestion, here's some screenshots of how to double check to see if you have any triggers set in the UI.

On the pipeline screen in your first screenshot, press edit to bring up the pipeline yaml. Within this click the 3 dots and select triggers
[image]

You should then see the CI triggers, and on the left a warning that anything you set will override the triggers in the yaml file
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Disable trigger on branch changes in scheduled trigger

I checked your grammar and it should be correct, but I couldn't test it for a short period of time, so I simply changed the grammar to 2 minutes instead of 4 o'clock every day：

```
schedules:
- cron: "*/2 * * * *"
  displayName: Testing daily run
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

You could also change it for test. And it works as expect.

Please check if the YAML is under the **master** branch.

And if it under the master branch, you could try to add the trigger from the UI to overwrite the YAML:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the "trigger: none" should be enough to disable this behaviour see: [Opting out of CI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#opting-out-of-ci)

Comment: The op shows they have this option, but it still is not working as expected. Please share a working yml script that you have tested to work as per questions requirements.